# Setting images source from web

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, webclient, bitmapimage

I am trying to set the source of images as follows :

```
    private void buttonGet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string website_url =HttpUtility.UrlEncode( textBoxURL.Text);
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
        Uri favIconUri = new Uri("http://g.etfv.co/"+ website_url ,UriKind.Absolute);
        wc.OpenReadAsync(favIconUri, wc);

    }
void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
        {
            try
            {

                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(e.Result);
                image1.Source = image;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Exception handle appropriately for your app  
                int i = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Either cancelled or error handle appropriately for your app  
        }
    }
}
```

I get exception :
`{"The request is not supported. "}` in line `image.SetSource(e.Result);`

The text box url is "http://google.com"
so the url formed is : "http://g.etfv.co/http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com"
I am unable to figure out a simple thing.

I tried with simple url as "http://img.technospot.net/Windows-Phone-7-Theme-Symbian.jpg" (instead of "http://g.etfv.co/foo-bar" and then it works but not the way I coded.

Anything incorrect ?

Comment: Why not just do new BitmapImage(favIconUri)?

Comment: tried that .. doesn't work.
I wanted to show some progress etc

Comment: The image doesn't appear nor does it throw an error in that case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the image that is returned is of type "ICO" which is not supported by BitmapSource. Only PNG and JPEG are supported.

Other formats such as GIF and ICO can only be read using a custom decoder.

Try using a different service to get the favicon:

http://www.getfavicon.org/results.php?url=google.com&t=png

will give you a PNG which BitmapSource will happily load.

Comment: http://www.getfavicon.org/?url=http://www.programmableweb.com/api/faviconz/favicon.png